# How can we combine readLockCheckInterval and maxMessagesPerPoll in camel file component configuration?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, io, apache-camel, nio

We are facing problem that camel file component readLockCheckInterval allow single file to be processed at a time and for next file camel lock, it will wait for readLockCheckInterval time. We have 10000 or more files which we want to process in parallel. I want to use maxMessagesPerPoll attribute for accessing multiple file per poll but with readLockCheckInterval because camel release the file lock if the file is still being copied. It will be great help if there will be any other way to achieve solution to above problem. Route configuration I am trying is as below,

from("inputFolder?recursive=true&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=5000&readLockTimeout=20000&maxMessagesPerPoll=5&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=true")

Comment: I think we have a JIRA ticket logged about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9324

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I think we need to write custom strategy to read files which are already copied to input folder and keep on try to acquire lock with files which are being copied.

Comment: For now I have written custom strategy to make it work but still please update us if it will be fixed in next release or we have any alternate approach to achieve above functionality.

Comment: Remember to use the vote in the JIRA. Also you are welcome to share your custom code and link from the JIRA so we can take a look

Comment: @ClausIbsen: so the jira ticket is not camel-ftp specific? It is a more generic issue?