# Parallel processing of multiple files using Apache Camel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I have thousands of files to process each individually. 
I used Apache Camel to process the files

from("file:C:\datafiles\input?readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=100&readLockCheckInterval=20")
.process(new MyProcessor()).to("file:C:\datafiles\output");

I do each file one at a time and it takes 30 minutes.

I'm thinking I can do this processing in 10 simultaneous threads, 10 files at a time, and I might be able to do it in 3 minutes instead of 30.

My question is, what is the "correct" way to achieve my 10 threads? And when one is done, create a new one to a max number of 10.

When I searched the internet I got some suggestions like using

1. maxMesssagesPerPoll
2. threads(10)
3. Aggregators

But I do not have anything to do with Aggregators here, just need to process each file from one remote location, process it and then place them in another remote location.

Comment: Creating multiple Route instances was another option found on the net. But I am looking for an option using multithreading approach instead of new RouteBuilder instances. As given references what I have searched are not suitable for my implementation, hope this helps.

Comment: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Input-directory-with-multiple-file-consumers-tp5713788p5716340.html

Comment: Thread pools and seda queues is what I used to do parrallel imports. Can we see some code.

Comment: from("file:C:\datafiles\input?readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=100&readLockCheckInterval=20") .process(new MyProcessor()).to("file:C:\datafiles\output");

Answer (score 3):

Can use the below code to achieve multithreading.

```
public class RouterConfig extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C:\datafiles\input?readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=100&readLockCheckInterval=20&maxMessagesPerPoll=3") 
        .threads(3, 3, "myThread")
        .process(new MyProcessor())
        .to("file:C:\datafiles\output");
    }
}
```

Here threads api will create 3 threads.
maxMessagesPerPoll=3 will pick 3 files at one poll and pass one file to one thread, like wise here it picks 3 files (file1, file2, file3) and gives one file 3 threads (thread1, thread2, thread3).

- so, "file1" will be processed by "thread1" and
- "file2" will be processed by "thread2"
- "file3" will be processed by "thread3"

Comment: Only if the processing of each file takes long this is helps. Since there is a known issue with `readLock=changed` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780257/how-can-we-combine-readlockcheckinterval-and-maxmessagesperpoll-in-camel-file-co